# Adding Spatialite table with clip results in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, sql, spatialite, clip

I have 2 layers and I want to make a clip of layer 1 with layer 2 in SpatiaLite (I'm using the DB Manager within QGIS).

That's the code I'm using:

```
create table clipped_lines as
select * from lines, estensione
where st_intersects(lines.GEOMETRY, extension.geom)
```

The table is created but it is not a geographical object so I cannot add it to the QGIS map canvas.

The problem (I think) is that the geom column is seen as a normal column and not as a GEOMETRY column. I've tried to update the column with:

```
ALTER TABLE clipped_lines
ALTER COLUMN geom TYPE GEOMETRY(LineString,4326);
```

but nothing happened.

I thought that the `st_intersects` function updates automatically the geom column.

Comment: What type of geometry is `lines` (I guess a LINESTRING) and `extension` (or `estensione`, whichever one it really is)?

Comment: Hi @BradHards, yep **lines** is a LINESTRING while **estensione** is a MULTIPOLYGON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use RecoverGeometryColumn. The syntax is:

```
SELECT RecoverGeometryColumn('test_geom', 'the_geom',
4326, 'POINT', 'XY');
```

For more info see http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-cookbook/html/new-geom.html